# Limit available panes in the Views UI

Tags: views, 6

I'm trying to configure the [Views](http://www.drupal.org/project/views) UI so that users can only see specific panes (i.e. only fields, filters and style settings panes). I tested [SimpleViews](http://drupal.org/project/simpleviews) and [Views UI: Edit Basic Settings](http://drupal.org/project/views_ui_basic) modules, but it wasn't so useful.

Hiding panes with jQuery was also not a good way.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I might comment like your comment on SO got commented but instead, I'll just link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821736/limit-available-panes-in-the-views-ui

Comment: Did you find a solution?